# Revert inside a for loop

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, function, revert, code

If there is a revert inside a for loop that is inside a function, and the revert is triggered, will the whole function revert?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a revert within a loop inside a function triggers a full function revert due to its stack-based execution model, rolling back all changes made within the function.

Comment: thanks I would upvote you but don't have 15 reputation points yet